# TP4056 circuit - have I got this right?

Tags: circuit-design, coin-cell, tp4056

I've designed and built this circuit which seems to work, but this isn't my day job so if anyone's able to take a look at it and let me know if you can see any flaws or potential improvements I'd be very grateful.

Space is limited so I've tried to minimise component count and complexity.

A rechargeable coin cell is connected to battery +ve and 0V and drives three onboard flashing LEDs and some external LEDs wired in parallel, via a mercury tilt switch.

When 5V is connected to Vcc and 0V the battery charges and voltage is also applied to the gate of Q1 via R4, disconnecting the load from the battery (since I understand that simultaneously charging and discharging the battery is a Bad Idea).

At the same time, the 5V charging voltage is supplied directly to the LEDs via the additional resistor R9, to allow for the increase in voltage from the 3.7V when powered by the battery. Diode D6 prevents charging current being dumped into the drain of Q1 (maybe not necessary?)

[image]

Comment: "simultaneously charging and discharging the battery is a Bad Idea" - no, it's just physically impossible. It would be like a car going forwards and backwards at the same time.

Comment: D6 is necessary because the MOSFET's body diode would provide a charging path through R9 and bypass the TP4056. You might want to consider one in series with R9 to prevent the battery being discharged through something connected to Vcc but not powered up.

Comment: Good points, thanks. Vcc comes from the charging port so should only be connected to an active power supply but I'm sure I can find room for another diode to be on the safe side. 

Regarding charging/discharging, what happens if the load is connected permanently to the battery (ie no Q1 etc)? Does the TP4056 get confused because it's now trying to charge a fusion of battery + load?

Comment: Yes, the TP4056 is designed to charge a battery and nothing else. It will have no idea how much current is going into the battery and how much into the load.